# Responsive image cutting off on mobile

Tags: html, css

Div is responsive but cutting off small section of image. The only thing in the div is an image.

```css
#header {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400.png" width="800" height="400" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Just want the image to shrink down for mobile users but it's cutting off the left side of the image slightly. I can "fix" it by making the image smaller but then it doesn't look good on desktop.

Comment: you can use CSS object-fit property on the image. see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Comment: I tried it, didn't work, giving me the same problems. Cuts off slightly on the left side. Not sure if my image or code is the problem. I haven't had this problem before with other images.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the fixed width and height for the img, due to which it will not shrink down on smaller devices. Switching to [relatives](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) sizes might help solve the problem. If not you might want to take a look at [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

```css
#header {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400.png" width="70%" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please don't use any height width inline for image tag. add this img style class i have added here. it will work fine.

```css
#header {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```